# Allow keyboard-shortcuts in input Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `tel` input and I limit the input to only numbers, backspace and tab like this

```
$("#phone").on('keydown',function(e) { 
var a = [];
var k = e.which;
for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
    a.push(i);
a.push(8);
a.push(9);
if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But when in the input you can not then use keyboard shortcuts like `cmd+R`  or `ctl+R` to refresh and such this is not  a big deal, but I was wondering if there is a way to see it the user is trying use a keybaord short cut? (Refresh in particular.)?

Thank

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. I don't see any way to accomplish this. Browsers usually have a refresh button anyway.

Comment: @www139 Its not a big problem Im more just curious?

Comment: Ok, understandable :)

Comment: I'd suggest restricting the types of characters that can be kept inside the input box. So basically on a `keyup` event, check the value of the input box and remove any non-numbers, backspaces, and tabs.

Comment: @NickZ could you provide an example?

Comment: @iqueqiorio I posted an answer to this question with an example - check it out

Answer (score 0):

To capture combinations of keys, you can use an `&&` statement in your conditions. For Windows, you should use `event.ctrlKey` and for Mac, you should use `event.metaKey`.

For Windows

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 82)
```

For Mac

```
if (event.metaKey && event.keyCode === 82)
```

> The `metaKey` property returns a Boolean value that indicates whether or not the "META" key was pressed when a mouse event was triggered.
>
> Not all keyboards have the meta key. It is common for Sun microsystem keyboards, and MIT and LISP machine keyboards. The meta key is either labeled "META" or marked with a solid diamond "◆" symbol.
>
> On Mac keyboards, the META key is represented by the the "Command/Cmd" ("⌘") key

Comment: `event.ctrlKey` does this also do cmd for mac, or is that different?

Comment: For mac, you use `event.metaKey`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 91)
        console.log('command key!');

    if (e.keyCode === 17)
        console.log('ctrl key!');
});
```

Handle those keys appropriately.

Comment: Okay this works and allows the cnd/ctrl key to be pressed but how do I also let R to be pressed when one of those is down, I tried adding an `if` to check for R on the inside but that doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

A better way to accomplish what you're trying to do is simply restrict the type of characters that the input will allow to keep. Basically, each time a `keydown` event is fired, check the input and remove any characters that aren't numbers or spaces.

Consider the following:

```
$("#phone").on('keydown',function() { 
     // This will remove all characters that are not digits between 0-9
     this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
}
```